# Optimal curves on planar annular regions

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations

I am looking for references on optimal curves in planar annular regions

More precisely, on simple closed curves of class $C^2$ which simultaneously minimizes a finite number of functionals from the set of the curves in a planar annular region — which may be thought of as, or a $C^2$-diffeomorphism of $ S^1 \times \left[0, 1 \right] $, or an homotopy equivalent to $ S^1 $ compact neighborhood of a $C^2$ simple closed curve, or a compact connected orientable $2$-manifold of class $C^2$ and genus $1$ — having non-zero winding number around the bounded region by the inner ring to the real numbers. Also it is fine to consider periodic curves with domain $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ rather than simple closed curves.

Picture those regions as racing circuits and the curves as racing cars trajectories on these racing circuits.

Any reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what sense are your curves "optimal"?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thanks for pointing that! It should be clearer now.